# Sorting a linked list with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I am wanting to insert nodes according to their location year and month. So basically all locations are clumped together and then they are sorted according to the year and the months. Below is the code in my linkedlist.cpp file. My insert function I believe is the main cause of my issues. When I use the overload operator to print the list and then the copied list, it is only printing one of the inserted nodes.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "linkedlist.h"
    using namespace std;

    LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){
        // Implement this function
    }

    LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
        // Implement this function
        this->clear();
    }

    LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& source) {
        // Implement this function
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        Node* tempNode = source.head;

        while(tempNode != nullptr)  {
            insert(tempNode->loc, tempNode->yr, tempNode->mo, tempNode->temp);
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }

    }

    LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList& source) {
        if (this != &source) {
            this->clear();
            Node* tempNode = source.head;
            while(tempNode != nullptr){
                insert(tempNode->loc, tempNode->yr, tempNode->mo, tempNode->temp);
                tempNode = tempNode->next;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }



    void LinkedList::insert(int location, int year, int month, double temperature) {
        // Implement this function
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->loc = location;
        newNode->yr = year;
        newNode->mo = month;
        newNode->temp = temperature;
        Node* tempNode = head;

        if(tail == nullptr & head == nullptr){
            newNode = head;
        }
        while(tempNode != nullptr){
            if((tempNode->loc == newNode->loc) && (tempNode->yr == newNode->yr)){
                if(tempNode->mo > newNode->mo){
                    newNode->next = tempNode->next;
                    tempNode->next = newNode;
                }
                if(tempNode->mo < newNode->mo){
                    newNode->next = tempNode;
                }
            }
            if(tempNode->loc > newNode->loc){
                newNode->next = tempNode->next;
                tempNode->next = newNode;
            }
            if(tempNode->loc < newNode->loc){
                newNode->next = tempNode->next;
                tempNode->next = newNode;
            }
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }
    }

    void LinkedList::clear() {
        // Implement this function
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node* deleteNode = current;
            current = current->next;
            delete deleteNode;
        }
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    void LinkedList::print() const {
        /* Do not modify this function */
        print(cout);
    }

    void LinkedList::print(ostream& os) const {
        /* Do not modify this function */
        os << *this;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LinkedList& ll) {
        // Implement this function
        Node* tempNode = ll.head;
        if (tempNode == nullptr) {
            os << " <Empty List>";
        }
        while (tempNode != nullptr) {
            if (tempNode != ll.head)
            cout << " " << tempNode->loc << " " << tempNode->yr << " " << tempNode->mo << " " << tempNode->temp << endl;
        }
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
        return os;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: off topic: you want to use `&&` ([logical AND](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)) rather than `&` (bitwise AND) here: `if(tail == nullptr & head == nullptr)`, but know that if you fix this bug you will reveal two others, so expect more debugging to follow.

Comment: @user4581301 ahh yes thank you. Did not see that I had forgotten the second &